# Add a devDependency that executes a shell command

Tags: shell, gruntjs, grunt-shell

To run an external command as a grunt task, we can use grunt-shell, grunt-exec or grunt-spawn.

To build a project, I must ensure that a certain tool is installed. The tool isn't available via npm, but requires running a command to install. So I need to add a **devDependency** to a `package.json` that involves executing an external command. How can I do that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can define preinstall/postinstall commands in the [scripts block](https://www.npmjs.org/doc/misc/npm-scripts.html) of the `package.json`:

```
{
  "scripts": {
    "preinstall": "your install-command",
    "postinstall": "your install-command"
  }
}
```

Choose which one fits your needs!

Comment: Thanks! Unfortunately it looks like you can't pass an array of commands to the scripts. I wanted to add comments explaining what the script does, but JSON doesn't support comments. A way to bypass that would be to pass a shell comment (or echo) as the first value of "preinstall" in an array, but passing an array causes the scripts to do nothing.

Comment: you could concatenate commands with `&&`. i know it's not the optimal solution but it should work: `"preinstall": "echo 'this is your comment' && your-command"`